# If a product of relatively prime integers is an $n$th power, then each is an $n$th power

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $n$, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers with $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $ab = c^n$, then there are positive integers $d$, and $e$ such that $a = d^n$ and $b = e^n$.

I know that (by Bezout) $\gcd\left(a,b\right) = 1$ implies $ax + by = 1$ for some integers $x$ and $y$, and also that $\gcd\left(a^n,b^n\right) = 1$, but this does not help me.

Comment: Have you considered the prime factorizations of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: @kira: Please ask questions, don't give orders. Also: please make your titles informative, not sentence fragments.

Comment: obvious assuming the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Comment: @kira: The title describes your problem exactly; why did you change it back to not having mark-up and to the old phrasing?

Comment: Because of this:@kira: Please ask questions, don't give orders. Also: please make your titles informative, not sentence fragments. – Arturo Magidin 3 hours ago

Comment: @kira: I had in fact, changed the title to being informative; you attempted to state the entire thing with notation and all. Think of titles as indexing features; you don't put the entire content of the theorem in the index, just enough information for people to know what you are talking about. Another tip: the `@someone` actually "pings" people and lets them know you are talking to them. I did not know you had written this in response to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course [it is easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1104334/242) using existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations. Below is a more general proof using gcd's (or ideals) that has the benefit of giving an explicit closed form.

$ab=c^n \overset{\rm Lemma}\Rightarrow c=(a,c)(b,c) \,\Rightarrow\, ab = (a,c)^n(b,c)^n\Rightarrow  \dfrac{a}{(b,c)^n}\! = \dfrac{(a,c)^n}b$ $\,\Rightarrow\begin{align} a &= (a,c)^n\\ b &= (b,c)^n\end{align}$

where the last inference uses [Unique Fractionization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) [both fractions are irreducible by $(a,b)\!=\!1$]

**Lemma** $\ \ \color{#c00}{c\mid ab},\,\ \color{#0a0}{(a,b,c)=1}\ \Rightarrow \ c = (a,c)(b,c)\ [=\,  (ab,c\color{#0a0}{(a,b,c)}) = (\color{#c00}{ab,c}) = c\,],\,$ where the braced proof uses [gcd "polynomial" arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242), i.e. associative, commutative, distributive laws.

**Alternatively** $\ (a,c)^n\! \overset{\rm\color{#C00}F}= (a^n,c^n) = (a^n,ab) = a(a^n,b) = a$ and $\,(b,c)^n = b\,$ by symmetry, where we have invoked $\rm\color{#c00}F$ = [GCD Binomial Theorem (Freshman's Dream)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1199979/242).

As $ $ [Weil remarks,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/diophantine-equations-solved-using-algebraic-numbers/18187#18187) $ $ this result can be viewed as the essence of Fermat's method of *infinite descent*. $ $ It generalizes to rings of algebraic integers but depends upon much deeper results in this more general context, viz. the finiteness of the class number and Dirichlet's unit theorem.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/675937/242) for a comparison of the alternative proof (case $\,n = 2$) to the common Bezout-based proofs.