# Squares in arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

It is easy to find 3 squares (of integers) in arithmetic progression. For example, $1^2,5^2,7^2$.

I've been told Fermat proved that there are no progressions of length 4 in the squares. Do you know of a proof of this result?

(Additionally, are there similar results for cubes, 4th powers, etc? If so, what would be a good reference for this type of material?)

---

**Edit, March 30, 2012:** The following [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92707/squares-in-an-arithmetic-progession) in MO is related and may be useful to people interested in the question I posted here.

Comment: See also [Fibonacci's Lost Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27317/242) for another variation, which has a very pretty proof by descent.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are a few proofs: [1](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/4squarearithprog.pdf), and the somewhat bizarre [3](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath044/kmath044.htm). *I'd previously linked to Kiming's exposition to prove this result, but the link has been removed. This is the proof described in lhf's answer --- and I think of this as a very elementary approach.*

Unfortunately, there are no cases where you have nontrivial arithmetic progressions of higher powers. This is a string of proofs. Carmichael himself covered this for n = 3 and 4, about a hundred years ago. But it wasn't completed until Ribet wrote a paper on it in the 90s. His paper can be found [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/acta.pdf). The statement is equivalent to when we let $\alpha = 1$. Funny enough, he happens to have sent out a notice on scimath with a little humor, which can still be found [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/96/fermatlike).

Comment: The link at the end from sci.math is now broken. It looks like the whole "Mathematical Atlas" site that Rusin set up and hosted on his webpages is now gone.

Comment: @KCd, the link is still available through the Internet Archive: [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130604030207/http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/96/fermatlike).

Comment: Link number 2 is also gone. No backup in Internet Archive.

Answer (score 10):

A quick Google search found this paper: [On 4 Squares in Arithmetic Progression by Ian Kiming](http://www.math.ku.dk/%7Ekiming/lecture_notes/2007-2008-elliptic_curves/4_squares_in_arithmetic_progression.pdf). It contains a sketch of an elementary proof at the end and cites  Dickson's *History of the theory of numbers*. It is reproduced below.

---

There do not exist $4$ rational squares in arithmetic progression:

**Theorem 1.** Suppose that $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are rational numbers such that:
$$\beta^2-\alpha^2=\gamma^2-\beta^2=\delta^2-\gamma^2.$$
Then $\pm\alpha=\pm\beta=\pm\gamma=\pm\delta$.

1.2. **Elementary proof.** The following elementary proof of theorem 1 is outlined by Dickson in [9], p. 440. As an exercise, fill in the details of the following steps.

**I.** To prove theorem 1 assume that we are given rational numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ satisfying the hypothesis of the theorem. We may assume that they are relatively prime, non-negative integers. The theorem then states that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta$. Assume that this is not true. Then we see that $\alpha^2<\beta^2<\gamma^2<\delta^2$.

Show that $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)=\gcd(\beta,\gamma)=\gcd(\gamma,\delta)=1$ and that $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ are all odd. Conclude that $\gcd(\beta+\alpha,\beta-\alpha)=\gcd(\gamma+\beta,\gamma-\beta)=\gcd(\delta+\gamma,\delta-\gamma)=2$.

**II.** Defining positive integers $a,b,c,d$ by:
$$2a:=\gcd(\beta+\alpha,\gamma+\beta),\\
2b:=\gcd(\beta+\alpha,\gamma-\beta),\\
2c:=\gcd(\beta-\alpha,\gamma+\beta),\\
2d:=\gcd(\beta-\alpha,\gamma-\beta),$$
show that we have:
$$\beta+\alpha=2ab,\\
\beta-\alpha=2cd,\\
\gamma+\beta=2ac,\\
\gamma-\beta=2bd,\\
\delta+\gamma=2bc,\\
\delta-\gamma=2ad.$$

**III.** Then $(a+d)b=(a-d)c$ and $(c+d)a=(c-d)b$, and we have the number $\gcd(a+d,a-d)$ and $\gcd(c+d,c-d)$ are both either $1$ or $2$. We can then conclude that
$$a+d=mc,\\a-d=mb,\\c+d=nb,\\c-d=na,$$
with $m,n\in\{1,2\}$.

**IV.** The conclusion in the last step is incompatible with the positivity of $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Very nice write-up. Thank you!

Comment: The link seems to be dead. Does anyone have a backup or another link to the exposition?

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal, that's too bad. Perhaps you can ask the author [Ian Kiming](http://www.math.ku.dk/english/staff/?pure=en/persons/108579) ?

Comment: What a terrific idea! I did, and the author says the link should be restored soon. He also says his treatment is the same as in Cassels' book on elliptic curves.

Comment: 2019 and the links are still dead. All of the links on that website, actually.

Answer (score 6):

My favourite proof of this is [Van der Poorten's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.3850.pdf) — it uses descent, as Fermat almost certainly would have.