# Consecutive consecutive sums of equal value

Tags: arithmetic

Given the list of counting numbers, what is the largest amount of consecutive consecutive sums of equal value that can be found? Is there a limit?

For example,

[1, 2] and [3] are two consecutive consecutive numbers that both add up to 3.

(If somebody understands the question and has a better way of phrasing, please do help me rephrase this.)

Comment: I roughly understand what you're saying but some details aren't clear.  Does the first sum have to start at $1$ or could it be something like $[4,5,6]$ and $[7,8]$?  Also, when you say largest "amount" do you mean the sum is large or the number of blocks is large (in your example, two)?

Comment: It can start at any given number and amount means the number of blocks.

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but for two blocks you can get them arbitrarily big. For example, take $(1,a,b)$ and the blocks $1,\dots,a$, and $a+1,\dots,a+b$. Then $a,b$ are given by simple linear recurrence relations. The first few terms are $(1,14,6),(1,84,35),(1,492,204),(1,2870,1189),(1,16730,6930)$

Answer (score 2):

You can't have more than two.
There is this pattern:  $1+2=3,4+5+6=7+8,9+10+11+12=13+14+15,...$
where the first sequence goes from $n^2$ to $n(n+1)$, but it's only two in a row.
Multiply by eight, then $$8[(m+1)+(m+2)+...+n]=8\left[\frac{n(n+1)}2-\frac{m(m+1)}2\right]=(2n+1)^2-(2m+1)^2$$
So a sequence of three of these will have
$$(2n+1)^2-(2m+1)^2=(2p+1)^2-(2n+1)^2=(2q+1)^2-(2p+1)^2$$
so you have four squares in arithmetic progression.
[This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43519/squares-in-arithmetic-progression) shows you can't have four squares in arithmetic progression.

Comment: *1 a neat solution!

Comment: Does this consider sequences like [3,12][13,17] that does not follow the pattern?

Comment: Yes, as it is related to $625-25=25^2-5^2=35^2-25^2=1225-625$

Comment: @Empy2 $15$ has three sums. $$15 = 7+8\quad = 4+5+6\quad = 1+2+3+4+5$$

Comment: They are consecutive but not consecutive consecutive because they overlap

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$\quad N=x+(x+1)+(x+2)+\cdots +(x+n)\\
\implies N=\frac{(n^2 + 2 n x + n + 2 x)}{2}
= \frac{(2x+n)(n+1)}{2}\\
$$
N is the sum of consecutive numbers if and only if $N$ is factorable as
$\space 2N=(2x+n)(n+1).$

For example
$$N=7 \rightarrow 
14=\big(2(x)+n\big)\big(n+1\big)=\big(2(3)+1\big)\big(1+1\big),
\quad 7=3+4$$

Now we solve for $x$ and, try values of $n$ where
$\quad\sum_{1}^{n} k<N\quad $ and the highest integer solution where
$\quad (1+2+3+\cdots+n)<N\quad$ indicates $n$ as the maximum possible number of consecutive integers sums equal to $N$.

$$N=\frac{(n^2 + 2 n x + n + 2 x)}{2}
   =\frac{2(n+1)x+n(n+1)}{2}
\implies x=\frac{2N-n(n+1)}{2(n+1)}$$

The number $n$ will sometimes be greater than the number of sums equal to $N$ but it will never be less. Here is a table showing the results for
$\quad 1\le N\le 25$

\begin{align*}
(N,n)\qquad &\text{  consecutive integer sums}\\
(2,0)\qquad &2\\
(3,1)\qquad &3 = 1+2\\
(4,0)\qquad &4\\
(5,1)\qquad &5 = 2+3\\
(6,2)\qquad &6 = 1+2+3\\
(7,1)\qquad &7 = 3+4\\
(8,0)\qquad &8\\
(9,2)\qquad &9 = 4+5\quad = 2+3+4\\
(10,3)\qquad &10 = 1+2+3+4\\
(11,1)\qquad &11 = 5+6\\
(12,2)\qquad &12 = 3+4+5\\
(13,1)\qquad &13 = 6+7\\
(14,3)\qquad &14 = 2+3+4+5\\
(15,4)\qquad &15 = 7+8 \quad  = 4+5+6 \quad = 1+2+3+4+5\\
(16,0)\qquad &16\\
(17,1)\qquad &17=8+9\\
(18,4)\qquad &18=5+6+7\quad =3+4+5+6\\
(19,1)\qquad &19=9+10\\
(20,4)\qquad &20 =2+3+4+5+6\\
(21,6)\qquad &21=1+2+3+4+5+6\quad =6+7+8=10+11\\
(22,3)\qquad &22=4+5+6+7+8\\
(23,1)\qquad &23=11+12\\
(24,1)\qquad &24=7+8+9\\
(25,4)\qquad &25=3+4+5+6+7\quad =12+13\\
\end{align*}