# Finding square numbers in arithmetic progression

Tags: square-numbers

Say I have three square numbers

(these are squared whole numbers greater than ZERO)

```
S1 < S2 < S3
```

how would you go about showing that the following is possible

```
S2 - S1 = S3 - S2
```

e.g. the difference between S1 and S2 is the same as that between S2 and S3

Comment: It's not true for 1,4,9

Comment: $9-4\ne 4-1{}{}{}$

Comment: I agree, is it true for any set of three squared numbers?

Comment: untrue for all sets of squares

Comment: duplicate of (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43519)

Comment: You should think carefully about your question and phrasing it.  It often helps you answer your own question.  To show it is possible just takes one case.  Did you want to know if there are infinite classes of solutions?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. My enthusiasm for maths got the better of me. What I actually need are two pairs of squares that are equi distance "Before" and "After" a "central" square. the distance refers to the difference between the squares and the pivot square. e.g. I need the difference between S2 and S1 to be identical to the difference between S3 and S2. the squares involved do not have to be consecutive.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $1^2,5^2,7^2$ works.

For more solutions you can take $(m^2+2mn-n^2)^2,(m^2+n^2)^2,(n^2+2mn-m^2)^2$ for $n>m$.

Comment: Agree, is that it though?

Comment: @Hector:  that is sufficient to answer your question.  If you ask if something is possible an example is enough.  There are many other cases.

Comment: edited to add a general solution @Hector

Comment: It would be interesting to know the "genesis" of your formulas.