# a theorem of Fermat

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

While I was surfing the web, searching things about math, I read something about a particular theorem of Fermat. It said: let $a$ and $b$ be rational. Then $a^4-b^4$ cannot equal the square of a rational number, so $a^4-b^4\neq c^2$ with $c$ rational. My question is: did I understand the theorem? if not, what is the actual theorem? if yes, how can I proof this or is that too difficult?

Comment: Yes, this is a theorem of Fermat, in the equivalent version that there are no non-trivial *integer* solutions. The proof is by Fermat's Method of Infinite Descent, a version of strong induction. It is one of the few number theoretic assertions of Fermat for which he sketched enough of a proof for us to know for sure how he did it.

Comment: See my [speculative reconstruction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27309/help-to-understand-a-proof-by-descent/27317#27317) of Fibonacci's Lost Theorem $= \rm FLT_4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a theorem, No, it's not too difficult to prove, and you can try in some analytic number theory book for the proof, say in

http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.co.il/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-4.html

or in

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/4400flt4.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400flt4.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

That's right, modulo a small precision: Fermat proved that there are no solutions other than the obvious ones, such as $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$,  $(1,0,1)$, etc.. See for instance [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents#n.C2.A0.3D.C2.A04).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you understand the theorem. The proof uses the method of "infinite descent" (a sibling of reductio ad absurdum, or proof by contradiction).

There is a walkthrough proof here:- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents#Application_to_right_triangles

But did you maybe want just a hint instead??

Answer (score 2):

If $b\neq 0$, yes, it's true. It follows from the fact that
$$ a^4-b^4=c^2 $$
has no **integer** solutions, under the assumptions $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $b\neq 0$.
On the other hand, if $c,d$ are two coprime integers such that $c^2+d^2$ is a square, say $e^2$, than $e$ is the sum of two coprime squares. This is the key step of the proof.