# If $2xy$ is a perfect square, then $x^2+y^2$ cannot be

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I ask a question that is probably never proved a conjecture: if $x$ and $y$ are two natural numbers $> 1$ such that $2xy = N^2$ ( double their product is a perfect square ), x and y cannot be part of a Pythagorean triple , that is, there is no natural $M$, $M > 1$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = M^2$.

Answer (score 5):

This conjecture is true.

Assume for contradiction such $x$, $y$ exist. We may assume that $\gcd(x,y) = 1$ without loss of generality. Then according to $x^2+y^2=M^2$ there exist $m$ and $n$ of different parity and $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ such that $x = m^2-n^2$ and $y = 2mn$ ([Euclid's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple)), so we would need $mn(m-n)(m+n)$ to be a square.

As $m$, $n$, $m-n$, $m+n$ are all pairwise coprime (note exactly one of them is odd), this can only happen if each is a perfect square; if $m = a^2$, $n = b^2$ then we get $c^2 = a^4-b^4$, but this is [not possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893544/fermat-prove-a4-b4-c2-impossible).

Comment: Thanks, but y = 2mn  in Euclid's Formula ?

Comment: Yep. Fixed it, thanks. :)

Comment: Also, so we would need 2mn(m−n)(m+n) to be a square

Comment: @EnzoAlberio Note that $2yx$ is a square, that is $2(2mn)(m^2-n^2)=4mn(m^2-n^2)$ is a square. Therefore we can divide by 4 to see that $mn(m^2-n^2)$ is a square.