# When $(m+n)(m-n)$ is perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[If $2xy$ is a perfect square, then $x^2+y^2$ cannot be](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500877/if-2xy-is-a-perfect-square-then-x2y2-cannot-be?rq=1)
I was trying to prove this way -
Let assume $2xy = n^2$ and $x^2+y^2 = m^2$ exists. Now  -
$x^2+y^2  - 2xy = (m+n)(m-n)\\ (x-y)^2 = (m+n)(m-n)$
How do I continue to prove that such $m$ or such $x,y$ doesn't exists?

Comment: $(x-y,n,m)$ would be a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: Where did you see this question?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Yesterday :|

Comment: Okay. I asked where.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I was just browsing MSE .. and then find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both $2xy$ and $x^2+y^2$ are squares, then since $(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2,$ there would be two fourth powers whose difference is a square, known impossible except for trivial cases. [Technically $x=y=0$ works, but I'm assuming you want solutions in nonzero integers.]

Note: that impossibility proof isn't easy...