# Why $a^4 + b^4$ ($a, b$ are positive integers) is not a perfect square?

Tags: square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I've realized that there are maybe no positive integers $(a, b)$ that $a^4 + b^4$ is a perfect square, because I tested for $a, b \le 10000$ and cannot find any solution.

I think that's weird, and how to prove it?

Comment: Fermat proved this by "infinite descent". See texts on number theory.

Comment: I don't have a text of number theory. I'm not a university student. (and I'm a middle school student and only know high-school level maths) If you have a link, can you provide?

Comment: Googling "fermat's last theorem power of 4" gave me [this as the first result](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.no/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-4.html) and [this as the third](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/4400flt4.pdf).

Comment: Okay it helps - because when I googled it I only found the result of proof of $x^4-y^4=z^2$.

Comment: One pretty proof is via [Fibonacci's Lost Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27317/242)

Comment: Perhaps someone could consider making one (or more) of their comments into an answer, so the OP can accept one, and this post can move off the "Unanswered" queue. Thanks!