# Alternative proof to the proposition: 'If a,b,c,d,... are not divisible by p, for p a prime, abcd... also aren't divisible by p'

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

While reading the Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, Gauss shows a nice proof for the proposition before mentioned, also, I think that I have another, but I don't know if it is correct, correct me if i'm wrong. I'm a young self student and I want to learn from my mistakes. Thanks. And also sorry for some mistakes, I'm not an english native.

If
$$abcd \cdots$$ were divisible by p, that would mean that
$$abcd \cdots = kp.$$ But, if that would be right, that would mean that one of the values
$$a,b,c,d \cdots = p $$(Because p is prime and can't be factored as a product of other two numbers and if abcd... is a multiple of p, one of the prime factors would be p).

But that contradicts our first proposition, so
$$abcd...$$
can't be divisible by p.

Comment: This doesn't follow.  It's not true that if $abcd...$ is divisible by $p$ then one of $a,b,c,d, ...$ must be $p$.  e.g. $4*4 = 16$ is divisible by $p=2$...

Comment: But this is true because 4 = 2 *2, so at least one of the a,b,c,d... is the prime that is divisible.

Comment: Usually this sort of result is proven as a precursor to unique factorization.  As you remark, it follows trivially if you know unique factorization.

Comment: @Alex you aren't listening to JairTaylor's complaint correctly.  In $4\times 6 = 24$ despite $4\times 6$ being a multiple of $2$ neither $4$ nor $6$ is **equal** to $2$.  We aren't told that $a,b,c,d,\dots$ are all primes... There is no reason for one of $a,b,c,\dots$ to be *equal* to $p$... just that one of them will be *a multiple* of $p$.

Comment: Your statement that you claimed, "*if $abcd\dots = kp$ then one of the values $a,b,c,d,\dots \color{red}{=} p$*" is incorrect.  It should have read "one of the elements $a,b,c,\dots$ will be divisible by $p$."  The symbol $=$ is not the same as the symbol $\mid$.

Comment: As for proving this, you ought to share your definition of prime you are using.  The most useful definition of prime here is that $p$ is a prime iff for all integers $a,b$ the implication "$p\mid ab\implies p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$" holds.  The claim you are looking to prove here is merely the contrapositive extended to an arbitrary number of terms in the product.

Comment: Yes, you are right @JMoravitz , I appreciate a lot your comments, when I was referring that one of the a,b,c,d = p i was thinking that a,b,c,d were in lower terms eg: 16= 2^4 so a,b,c,d would be 2,2,2,2. Again, thanks for your comments, I've learned a lot for next proofs!

Answer (score 1):

it is true that if
$$
p = abc\cdots z
$$
is prime and all the factors are prime then one of the factors is $p$ itself.

How you prove that depends on what you have already proved. It follows easily from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which is essentially what you are using in your argument.

But it is usually proved using other arguments and used as an ingredient in the proof of the fundamental theorem.

Where does it appear in Gauss? After the FTA or on the way to it?

Answer (score 0):

That begs the principle, since you implicitly assume FTA = fundamental theorem of arithmetic. i.e. existence and uniqueness of factorizations into irreducibles. FTA  [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2008197/242) Euclid's Lemma, i.e. irreducibles are prime, i.e. if an irreducible divides a product it divides some factor. Conversely, Euclid's Lemma easily yields the *uniqueness* of factorizations into irreducibles (and this is one of the most common ways to prove it, after proving Euclid using Bezout's theorem for the gcd).

But a proof of the *equivalence* of these two statements is *not* a proof that they hold true in some particular number system. There are simple counterexamples showing how they can fail, e.g. the Hilbert numbers $\,\Bbb H = 1+4\:\!\Bbb N = \{1,5,9,13,\ldots\},\, $ the naturals $\equiv 1\pmod{\!4}.\,$ Here there exist *nonunique* factorizations into irreducibles, e.g. $\, 9\cdot 49 = 21^2.\,$ Thus, by above said equivalence, there also exist counterexamples to Euclid, here $\, 21\mid 9\cdot 49\,$ but $\, 21\nmid 9,49.\,$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690435/242) for more.