# What's a name for this elementary number theory lemma? Where can I find it online?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was going to ask another question about this - Origin - Elementary Number Theory, Jones, p23, Lemma 2.4 - but then I chanced on [If a product of relatively prime integers is an $n$th power, then each is an $n$th power](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21530/85100) and its duplicate. I'm bad at searching  and I don't want to instigate more duplicates, thence I want to check if there are any others on this before asking newly.

Is there a name for this Lemma so I can try to search for it here and on Google? If you find anything, please inform me exactly what you typed in.

> If $a_1,\dots,a_r$ are mutually coprime positive integers, and $a_1\dots a_r$ is an $m$-th power of some integer $m\ge2$, then each $a_i$ is an $m$-th power.

Comment: *Please* just ask the question on the main site. If it's a duplicate, we'll close it, no harm done.

Comment: @AlexBecker Can you please move this then or do I need to post newly?

Comment: I'm not aware that there's a specific 'name' for this, but it follows by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and also the following property of prime numbers: if $p$ prime is such that $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

Answer (score 0):

As [ah11950](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/136851/ah11950) pointed out, this lemma is not prominent enough to yield having it's own name. The best way to refer to it is probably as a "[consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)."

Comment: No, the lemma is most certainly important (e.g. see Weil's rmeark [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21637/242)). But it doesn't have a common name.