# Prove $x^3 + 3 =4y(y+1)$ has no integer solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Proof by contradiction: 
1. Suppose  $x^3 + 3 =4y(y+1)$ has an integer solution

2. Then  $x^3 + 3 =4y^2+4y$
3. Then  $x^3 + 3 + 4 = 4y^2 + 4y + 4$
4. Then $x^3 + 7  = (2y + 2)^2$

Not sure how to simplify it further...

Comment: How about considering your options $\mod 4$?

Comment: Your last step is wrong: $(2y+2)^2 = 4y^2+8y+4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x^3=4y^2+4y-3=(2y+3)(2y-1)$
These are two odd numbers with no common factor.
Since their product is a cube, they must both be cubes.

Comment: how is that a contradiction? You can have odd cubes that don't have common factors like 3^3 and 5^3?

Comment: But they don't differ by 4.  The difference between 1,8,27,64 grows quickly.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21637/242) for a proof that they must both be cubes.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:  $x^3+3=4y(y+1)$ implies $x^3=4y^2+4y-3=(2y+3)(2y-1)$, so $x^3$ is the product of two odd numbers that differ by $4$.  Can two such numbers have any factors in common?