# Prove $(2−1)^2−4$ is not a perfect cube for any integer

Tags: number-theory

Last week, my teacher asked us to prove this:
Prove that $(2−1)^2−4$ is not a perfect cube for any integer
I tried this approach:$y=2k$ and $y=2k+1$
but I couldn't prove it this way.

Comment: Hint:  Letting $z=2y-1$ you have $n^3=z^2-4=(z-2)(z+2)$.  Note that $\gcd (z-2,z+2)$ must be a divisor of $4$.

Comment: I don't understand why $gcd(z-2,z+2)|4$?

Comment: Hmm... same teacher as in this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914956/proof-not-a-perfect-square

Comment: $\gcd(z+2,z-2)=\gcd(z+2,z+2-(z-2))=\gcd(z+2,4)$

Comment: Say $d=\gcd(a,b)$.  Then $d\,|\,a$ and $d\,|\,b$ so $d$ divides, say, $b-a$.

Comment: thnx I got now. but still I don't know how to use that hint.

Comment: should I replace $(−2)(+2)$ with $gcd(z-2,z+2)*lcm(z-2,z+2)$?

Comment: ok, i will try to give the right hint... We have two numbers, $A, B\in\Bbb Z$, and their product is a perfect cube in $\Bbb Z$. Can it be that $A,B$ are not each a perfect cube? Can we exclude this from the landscape in the given situation... Feel free to answer and accept the own question! @ John Sparrow

Comment: My answer contained a mistake. Now I edited and it's OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(2 y - 1)^2 - 4=(2y-1+2)(2y-1-2)=(2y+1)(2y-3)$$
$(2y-3)$ and $(2y+1)$ are coprime. For euclidean algorithm

$\gcd (2y+1,2y-3)=\gcd(2y+1,4)=1$

because $(2y+1)$ is odd and is coprime with $4$

So the two numbers have no common factors. Thus or both are cubes or their product cannot be a cube.

As the difference is $4$ we see that $2y-3$ and $2y+1$ cannot be both cubes because beside the case $1^3-0^3=1$ the minimum difference between two cubes is $2^3-1^3=7$

Therefore $(2 y - 1)^2 - 4$ cannot be a cube.

Comment: @MarkBennet I am editing my answer. Don't downvote

Comment: @MarkBennet Now it should be fine

Comment: @PM2Ring I edited the answer the day before yesterday. $\gcd$ is 1 because the number are coprime