# $x^3 - 6 = 25y^2 + 35y$ has no non-zero integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I need to show that $x^3 - 6 = 25y^2 + 35y$ has no non-zero integer solutions.
I tried moving things around and factor. Or use modulo 5 and 7 reductions for something shady to become a quadratic residue of a prime. I also couldn't really come up with something to use infinite descent. Hints would be appreciated.

This was a problem for non-linear diophantine equations (Pythagorean triples, rational points on curves, Fermat's last theorem, Pell's equations, etc.) in last year's elementary number theory exam.

Comment: Where did you get this problem--homework, textbook, research question? That is good for giving people context.

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I added an edit

Comment: Actually $x^3=(5y+1)(5y+6)$, and gcd

Comment: @Hypernova Those 2 are relatively prime so can I say that they should both be cubes? Can that be a contradiction? Assuming that two cubes can't be that close?

Comment: @Zara That's not a bad idea but the solution is more general

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $$x^3=25y^2+35y+6=(5y+6)(5y+1)$$Now, not both $5y+6$ and $5y+1$ are cubes, since there are no two positive cubes that differ by less than $7$, so there is a prime $p$ that divides both factors.  But then $p$ divides their difference, and $p=5$.  But this is absurd, since $p\nmid 5y+1$.

Comment: i.e. by Euclid $(5y+6,5y+1) = (5,5y+1) = 1,\,$ so being coprime factors of a cube [they are both cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21637/242), contra their difference $= 5.\ $