# Proof that irrational coprime square root sums and products are always irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, radicals, square-numbers, rationality-testing

I probably phrased it very bad.

This is what I mean: $$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \neq R$$ x and y being non-square coprime natural numbers. 
And: $$\sqrt{xy} \neq R$$ x, y, **AND R** being coprime. 
Let's try to prove the second one, the product of irrational coprime square roots, by contradiction. $$\sqrt{xy}=R$$ Then $$xy=R^2$$ Since they are coprime this has been proven, I note that if x and y are coprime, but each one is not coprime with R, this would be true if and only if x AND y were perfect squares; example: $$\sqrt{4*9}=6$$ Now I know that, but *how do I **apply it** to try to prove the first hypothesis?* I'm thinking of somehow using the fact that $$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \neq R$$ can be transformed into  $$x+y+2\sqrt{xy} \neq R^2$$
 Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea for the second part, but you need to be much more precise to obtain a rigorous proof. Suppose $\,\sqrt{XY} = A/B\in \Bbb Q.\,$ Wlog we may assume that $\,A/B\,$ is reduced, i.e. $\,A,B\,$ are coprime. Squaring  $\,XY = A^2/B^2\,$ so $\,A^2 = XYB^2.\,$ Comparing the powers of a prime $\,p\,$ on both sides of the equation  we obtain $\, 2a = x + y + 2b,\,$ where $\,a\,$ is the power of $\,p\,$ in $\,A,\,$ etc. $ $ By $\,X,Y\,$ coprime, one of $\,x,y\,$ is $\,0,\,$ say $\,x=0,\,$ so $\,y = 2a-2b-0\,$ is even. Therefore every prime factor of $\,X\,$ and $\,Y\,$ occurs to even power, so $\,X\,$ and $\,Y\,$ are squares.

**Remark** $\ $ The proof depends crucially on the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic*, i.e. the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations. Be sure to understand the places where this is (implicitly) used above (e.g. it implies power additivity: the power of $\,p\,$ in $XY$ is $\,x+y).\,$ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/824180/242) for some other proofs, using gcd laws, or using induction and the *prime divisor property* $\,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b.$

Answer (score 2):

As you've already proven the first part, we need only show that
$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \neq R$
Now as you suggested we can prove that 
$x + y + 2\sqrt{xy} \neq R^2$
Where R is any rational number, x and y are integers.
As $\sqrt{xy}$ is not a rational number $x + y + 2\sqrt{xy} = V$ is not rational (as all terms are rational except $\sqrt{xy}$).  So V is not rational, thus $\sqrt{V}$ is not rational.  Thus there can exist no such rational R where $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = R$

Comment: The OP certainly did not *prove* the first part.