# Does this "distribution of factors" cover all possibilities?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have the Diophantine equation
$$3a^2(4a^2+1)=b(b+1). \tag{$\star$}$$

Each side can evidently be “separated” into two [integer] factors as
$$3a^2 \cdot (4a^2+1) = b \cdot (b+1).$$
Now I *believe* I can claim that, for some integers $p,q,r,s$, the system of equations
\begin{align}
 3a^2 &= pq, &&&
  b &= pr,  \\
 4a^2+1 &= rs, &&&
  b+1 &= qs
\end{align}
must cover all possibilities. Is this correct, or am I missing some case(s)?

EDIT: If this *does* cover all possibilities, then [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1009802/93271) should be valid to show that ($\star$) has no non-trivial integer solutions.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Is there any solution of this equation? Give at least one example. In addition to the trivial.

Comment: @individ: See edited question, and in particular the link.

Comment: That's why I wondered where the solutions can be.  This equation has not tried to solve it? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133348/consecutive-integer-squared-square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes: it’s an easy consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA). Here’s the proof of the general case.

**Proposition:**
If $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are positive integers with $ab=cd$, then there exist positive integers $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$ such that $a=pq$, $b=rs$, $c=pr$, and $d=qs$.

*Proof.*
We are given $ab=cd$. Set $p=\gcd(a,c)\ge1$, so that $a=pq$ and $c=pr$ for positive integers $q$ and $r$ with $\gcd(q,r)=1$. Hence $pqb = prd$, and dividing both sides by $p \ne 0$ leaves $qb = rd$. As $\gcd(q,r)=1$, the FTA implies $r \mid b$, say $b=rs$ for an integer $s \ge 1$. ‎Then $qrs=rd$, so $d=qs$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: https://second.wiki/wiki/vierzahlensatz