# What is stopping every Mordell equation from having a [truly] elementary proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

The *Mordell equation* is the Diophantine equation
$$Y^2 = X^3-k  \tag{1}$$
where $k$ is a given integer. There is no known single method — elementary or otherwise — to solve equation $(1)$ for all $k$, though there are various *ad hoc* methods which work on large classes of $k$, and there are [published] elementary solutions for **many** (though not **all**) $k$.

> For the scope of this discussion, I define “elementary” as pre-college level number theory — definitely excluding imaginary numbers, class numbers, imaginary quadratic fields, "advanced" UFDs, and so on; almost certainly excluding quadratic reciprocity and similar; but definitely including FTA (unique factorization in the regular integers), mathematical induction, polynomial division, simple modular arithmetic, and so on.

Emboldened by [my recent completely elementary solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1012777/93271) to [the Mordell equation for $k=-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955967/does-an-elementary-solution-exist-to-x21-y3), I am wondering if an elementary proof can be found for **every** Mordell equation. Since it is impossible to prove a negative, I guess my real question is this:

For any integer or class of integers $k$, are there any obvious impediments to the development of an elementary solution?

Comment: $Y^2 = X^3 + 7$ has no integer solutions. Would you consider this "a solution"?

Comment: Yes, by "solution" I mean "proof by which all integer solutions are obtained, or it is shown that there are no integer solutions". So if you can, using only elementary means [as described above], prove that $Y^2 = X^3 + 7$ has no integer solutions, that would be a non-counterexample to my implied conjecture [that all Mordell equations admit a completely elementary "solution"].

Comment: @KierenMacMillan One obstruction is that we don't know anything about $k$ except that it's an integer. The elementary soltions found so far rely on the properties of the integer (i.e, if it is a perfect square, perfect cube, it's form is $5x^2+1$ etc.). Btw, do you know where can we get these "elementary" proofs of Mordell Equations published? If so, can you please notify me. Thanks.

Comment: @MathGod: We know a bunch about $k$. It can be written as $k_1k_2^2$ where $k_1$ is squarefree. It's either of the form $2m$ with $m$ odd, or can be written as $(\tfrac{k+1}{2})^2 - (\tfrac{k-1}{2})^2$ if odd or $(m+1)^2-(m-1)^2$ if even. _etc._

Comment: As for your other question, feel free to email me if you want to chat about publication options.

Answer (score 3):

There is a well known elementary proof that the equation

$$ y^2 = x^3+7 $$

has no solution in integers $x,y$.

If $x$ is even, then $y^2 \equiv 3\pmod{4}$. Since this is not possible, $x$ must be odd. Hence $x^2-2x+4 \equiv 1+2x \equiv 3\pmod{4}$, and so there exists a prime $q$ such that $q \mid (x^2-2x+4)$ and $q \equiv 3\pmod{4}$. But then

$$ y^2+1 = x^3+8 = (x+2)(x^2-2x+4) $$

implies $q \mid (y^2+1)$, which is impossible for primes of the form $4k+3$.

We have shown that the Mordell equation corresponding to $k=7$ has no integer solutions. $\blacksquare$

Comment: How does this answer the original question?

Comment: This *is* the "elementary proof" for the case $k=-7$. See my comment below the OP, in which this was asked and answered.

Comment: Can somebody please tell me why this was downvoted?

Comment: @AT1089 it was probably downvoted because it does not answer the question.
It does however give some insight about the case k = -7 but that was already mentioned in the comments below the OP.
I upvoted btw.
In my opinion it is neither good nor bad so a score of 0 seems reasonable. Less than zero is a punishment despite effort.